# Inner element padding taking % from parent

Tags: css

This is very odd and im surprised i never encountered this problem before.

Basically i have a parent div full width. Then i have an inner div, with a fixed-width/ max-width setting. This div is centered via margin:auto.

I want this inner div to have a % padding, lets say 50%. The problem is that this 50% is not being represented as 300px, but as 50% of the parent element. I have really never seen this behaviour...

If i set the padding in PX, in this case 300px, it works as expected.

Any ideas what the problem might be ?

```
.content {
 background: gray;
 padding: 60px 0;
}
.inner{
 width:600px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:red;
 //padding-left:300px;
 padding-left:50%;
}
```

Here is an example of the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/qD246/1/

Btw, im using box-sizing:border box.

Comment: Why would you want 50% padding?

Comment: Percentages always look for the parent, not the percentage of the element it is on.

Comment: Are you using `box-sizing: border-box;` for your document?

Comment: @natewiley that's just easier for my example.
aledagrande: yes, border-box is used on *.
ntgCleaner: any suggestions then ?

Comment: You can just add another div inside inner and put the padding on that.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, that's how relative units work. The padding is a percentage of something, so it must have a reference point, which is the parent element. It's not a percentage of the screen as a universal rule.

Comment: So how would i manage to have a % as a padding for the inner element ?
By adding another div inside and giving that one a the % ?

Comment: Yes. As long as you have any sort of parent element with absolute dimensions, child elements can use percentage just fine. Mind you, it doesn't necessarily have to be the parent element. If an element takes a percentage from a parent, and then you have another child within the child, it will still work, as there is still a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply your padding on P tag, it works.

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
background: gray;
padding: 60px 0;
}
.inner{
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:red;

}
.inner p{
        padding-left:50%;
}
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/qD246/2/

Comment: problem is that .inner has many different children and i dont think its a good idea to give them all a specific padding.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest to give a spcific class to the padded paragraphs :
.inner .rightp for example

Comment: Or just create another `<div>` that contains those elements.